# How to upload generate pdf file in controller to S3 bucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, wicked-pdf

I am using wicked_pdf to generate pdf file and want to upload it on s3 bucket because heroku not save in public. But facing issues how to upload there or how to give s3 bucket path in save path.

Here is my controller code:-

```
pdf = render_to_string :pdf => "user_detail"

# then save to a file
save_path = Rails.root.join('pdfs','filename.pdf')
File.open(save_path, 'wb') do |file|
  file << pdf
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to [Anurag Aryan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49841769/4950680) answer you can use [Aws::S3::Object#put](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html). This is useful if the object is a string **or** an IO object that is not a file on disk:

```
filename = 'filename.pdf'
pdf = render_to_string :pdf => "user_detail"
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: ENV['AWS_REGION'])
obj = s3.bucket('your-s3-bucket-name').object(filename)

# upload pdf data as a string
obj.put(body: pdf)

# or as an IO object
save_path = Rails.root.join('pdfs', filename)
File.open(save_path, 'wb') do |file|
  file << pdf
  obj.put(body: file)
end
```

Here is [an example of file uploading on docs.aws.amazon.com](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpRuby.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [aws-sdk](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby) gem.

The gem looks for AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_REGION in your environment file so you need to add these. You can create a S3 resource for the region where your bucket exists and create an object with a unique file name and call upload_file as shown below.

```
require 'aws-sdk'

file_name = 'your-file.pdf'

s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: ENV['AWS_REGION'])
obj = s3.bucket('your-s3-bucket-name').object(file_name)
puts "Uploading file #{file_name}"
obj.upload_file("/Users/username/path/to/#{file_name}")
puts "Done"
```

Comment: but issue is that file is not saved anywhere so why this path ("/Users/username/path/to/#{file_name}")

Comment: I generate it in controller also

Answer (score 1):

This [S3](https://github.com/qoobaa/s3) gem can get you perform this pdf upload. Bucket Name, Access Key ID, Access Key Secret need to be passed.

```
filename = "invoice.pdf"
# render your pdf file
pdf = render_to_string(:pdf => filename, template: "invoice.html.erb")
# S3 upload Code goes here
service = S3::Service.new(:access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'], :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'])
bucket = service.buckets.find(ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'])
file = bucket.objects.build("invoices/#{filename}")
file.content = pdf
file.content_type = "application/pdf"
file.acl = :public_read
file.save
# Done, use the URL below as needed
s3url = "http://#{ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']}.s3.amazonaws.com/invoices/#{filename}"
```